# Issue on install ffmpeg on Debian 8

Tags: ffmpeg, debian

I try to install "ffmpeg" on my **Debian 8** and I have issues.

```
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

I have this errors...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavcodec57 (>= 10:3.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavdevice57 (>= 10:3.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavfilter6 (>= 10:3.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavformat57 (>= 10:3.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libva1 (>= 1.7.3) but 1.4.1-1 is to be installed
 x264 : Depends: libffms2-4 (>= 1:2.23) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Oups yes, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

these dependencies are available in the jessie backports.